# iPhone Screen turns on again after using proximity sensor

Tags: ios, iphone, proximitysensor, screen-off

I am currently working on a new Alert App. 
 
The user will act like that:

Set an alarm -> Press start -> Place the iPhone on the screen

In my app I am using `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setProximityMonitoringEnabled:YES];` to use the proximity sensor.

After a while the iPhone turns the screen on again and leaves it like that.

This problem is happening on my iPhone 5S. 
Actually when I use the phone app this problem does not occur.

I hope someone could help me with that.

Comment: What is the problem and what does your app do for user ?

Comment: The Problem is that the screen should stay off when I use the proximity Monitoring, but it is getting on again after a while.

My app is a normal alert clock.